# zip file on ubuntu without getting a cpgz file on extraction

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, zip, tar

I get a cpgz file when trying to extract the contents of a file created on an ubuntu system.
Tried with 7zip, rar, zip, tar, nothing works... I really need to get this to work, so if somebody had a lead or a solution, that would be great !

Comment: your question is a bit unclear.  are you asking how to create an archive that contains no .cpgz files?  (how are you creating the archive now?)  are you asking how to extract a .cpgz file?  both?

Comment: I know on OS X this happens when the file that I'm trying to extract is not really a zip file (i.e. some files I downloaded from Xerox were .zip when they should've been .dmg; opening with archive utility produced .cpgz files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in fact that the file wasn't a zip file at all
it only contained a php error message, which obviously couldn't be uncompressed

thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this extension is created from the cpio utility and then gzip those contents (possibly a flag to cpio similar to tar that automatically sends the file through gzip to compress/decompress it).

Comment: @Matrix Mole
how can i check this ?

here's the command i'm using : 
zip -r <zipfile name> <file 1> <file 2> <file 3> ...